# Anyone able to get prisma.io working on the new Apple Silicon M1 devices?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I read docker support was not ready yet, but docker recently published a preview of their new version that seems to be working.  Next issue is that MySQL images are only available on x86_64 and not arm, but MariaDb has one.  Unfortunately, I'm not versed enough in Docker to be able to get that working.  Finally, I tried installing prisma with a postgres db but couldn't get that working either.

Has anyone had success getting prisma working on the new Apple MC M1 devices?  If so, please advise how you got it working.

Edit: Here is the Error Message when I `prisma init` for a mysql db and run `docker-compose up -d`

"ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries"

I've come to learn that this is because there isn't a mysql image for arm yet (but there is one for mariadb).

So when I changed the docker-compose file to load the `mariadb` image instead, `docker-compose up -d` runs successfully, but when I open `http://localhost:4466` in my browser localhost refuses to connect.

The same "localhost refused to connect" result also occurs if I set up prisma for postgres or mongodb too.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: please edit your question to include the actual error messages and problems you experience when trying to install Prisma

Comment: Can you try to use the platform flag like `--platform amd64` (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/)